# Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function - on Ajax Call

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, ruby-on-rails-3

This error: "Uncaught TypeError: string is not a function" is returning on an Ajax call I'm trying to do.

The code is:

```
$('input.js-nome-produto-servico').live("keyup", function(ed, h){
    var $campo = ed.currentTarget;

    $campo.autocomplete({
        source: "<%=Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.busca_todos_produtos_servicos_por_nome_comercial_produto_servico_oportunidades_path%>?nome="+$campo.value,
        minLength: 2,
        change: function(event, ui) {
          bindLoadingAnimation();
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          preencheCamposCliente(campo);
        }
    });
});
```

The error is rising on $campo.autocomplete.

I know I should call something like:

```
$("#field-id").autocomplete({ .........
```

But I have several fields that must respond to the same "keyup" event on the same way and use the same class (js-nome-produto-servico).

So I tried to get the DOM object (an input) from the keyup function (ed). When I call the debugger, the variable $campo has the correct object, but autocomplete doesn't work.

I think I'm missing some JS/JQuery concepts here. Can anyone give me the correct way to do this?

Thank you very much!

Comment: `var $campo = $(ed.currentTarget);` But still you should not bind jQuery plugin inside keyup event handler. I think you simply need `$('input.js-nome-produto-servico').autocomplete({...})`. Without any `.live("keyup"`.

Comment: I could do that, but I need the characters that the user is typing on the field to search for results that will fill the autocomplete source. That's why I'm calling Live function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If anyone face the same problem, the solution is to use $(this) tag. So the code would be:

```
$('input.js-nome-produto-servico').live("keyup", function(ed, h){

$(this).autocomplete({
    source: "<%=Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.busca_todos_produtos_servicos_por_nome_comercial_produto_servico_oportunidades_path%>?nome="+$(this).val(),
    minLength: 2,
    change: function(event, ui) {
      bindLoadingAnimation();
    },
    select: function( event, ui ) {
      preencheCamposCliente($(this));
    }
});});
```

$(this) is the object that was affected by the 'keyup' event.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried the "search" event?  Like:

```
$('.your_class').autocomplete({
        source: "<%=Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.busca_todos_produtos_servicos_por_nome_comercial_produto_servico_oportunidades_path%>?nome="+ $(this).val(),
        //below I replace the Minlength
        search: function(){
          if ( $(this).val().length < 2 ) {
             return false;
          }
        }
        change: function(event, ui) {
          bindLoadingAnimation();
        },
        select: function( event, ui ) {
          preencheCamposCliente(campo);
        }
    });
```

See if it works?